# Is there a way to split the list in a row ?(Python pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

here is a code for my data frame's grouping:

```
import pandas as pd

#create a list
product_list = ["bag","necklece"]
sold__commentlist = [['nice to use',"bad"],["good",'can be improved']]

#dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame (columns = ['product','sold_comment'])

#plug the list into the dataframe
data['product'] = product_list
data ['sold_comment'] = sold__commentlist

data
```

this is the data frame I formed

```
    product      sold_comment
0   bag          [nice to use, bad]
1   necklace     [good, can be improved]
```

Could I ask how to change the data frame into this form?

```
    product      sold_comment
0   bag          nice to use
0   bag          bad
1   necklace     good 
1   necklace     can be improved
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Check [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) for that.

Comment: @Rabinzel checked it, thanks for your reminder.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

#create a list
product_list = ["bag","necklece"]
sold__commentlist = [['nice to use',"bad"],["good",'can be improved']]

#dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame (columns = ['product','sold_comment'])

#plug the list into the dataframe
data['product'] = product_list
data['sold_comment'] = sold__commentlist

data = data.explode('sold_comment')

print(data)
```